# Android email attachment all pictures in a folder

Tags: android, email, attachment

This code attaches a specific picture in a folder :

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+ "/pictures/test.jpg");
m.addAttachment(file.toString());
m.send();
```

But i want my application attaches all photos are in a folder without specifying their name. Is it possible ?

Comment: you must get all `fileName` and attach all file in for statement with your code

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329815/sending-an-e-mail-with-multiple-attachments?rq=1